# Android Studio 4.0.0 Java 8 library desugaring in D8 and R8 Build Error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, java-8

I start using new update Android Studio 4.0.0 and following the [enable support java 8 library desugaring in D8 and R8](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#j8-library-desugaring):

```
compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
         coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
```

and

```
dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.6'
    ...
}
```

I end up unable to build my application with the following error:

```
Unsupported desugared library configuration version, please upgrade the D8/R8 compiler.
```

For more over:

```
> Task :app:compileNoExtensionsDebugSources UP-TO-DATE

> Transform artifact desugar_jdk_libs_configuration-0.12.0.jar (com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs_configuration:0.12.0) with L8DexDesugarLibTransform
Error: Unsupported desugared library configuration version, please upgrade the D8/R8 compiler.

> Transform artifact databinding-common-4.0.0.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:4.0.0) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Unsupported desugared library configuration version, please upgrade the D8/R8 compiler.","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

> Transform artifact multidex-2.0.1.aar (androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
Unsupported desugared library configuration version, please upgrade the D8/R8 compiler.

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Unsupported desugared library configuration version, please upgrade the D8/R8 compiler.","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

> Transform artifact kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.72) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Unsupported desugared library configuration version, please upgrade the D8/R8 compiler.","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
Unsupported desugared library configuration version, please upgrade the D8/R8 compiler.
```

Do I missed any configuration here? How to fix this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I encountered the same issue after I upgraded the `coreLibraryDesugaring` in `build.gradle` to `com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.6`. My app was building fine until I did that dependency update. A suggestion popped up two hours ago when I passed by `build.gradle` and I just followed suit.

```
dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.6'
}
```

I reverted the dependency back to `com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.5` and the issue magically disappeared.

```
dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.5'
}
```

From this, I think that it is likely a bug with the compatibility of the new version of the dependency with the IDE (maybe an IDE update may follow up to resolve the issue, I don't know). Maybe we need to report it as an issue to Google, I have not tried that yet. :D

Actually, I created this Stack Overflow account just now to share this after I saw your post when I searched for a solution to my problem. :)

**Update**

As mentioned by @sgjesse from the R8 team, the changes from `1.0.5` to `1.0.6` are already reverted in the release of `1.0.7` to fix this issue, so `1.0.5` and `1.0.7` are just the same. See @sgjesse's answer for more details.

```
dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.7'
}
```

I moved to `1.0.7` to remove the warning on outdated dependency version. :)

P.S. I can't comment because I don't have 50 reputation yet. Thanks, @sgjesse! :)

Comment: thank you. It works like magic. Hope this will be fixed for the next update, cos I don't know where to report them :D. Anyway, yes, come along to help other people here solving the problems or share your experience, it is great. 

Comment: Yeah, I hope the issue is fixed soon. I don't know where or how to report this issue too either :D This site is great, thanks for the welcome, glad I helped! :)

Comment: This answer is pretty old and I'm getting the same issue now after updating from 1.1.5 to 1.2.0. Could it be a bug on the R8 again?

Comment: @Lance build tools 7.2.0 demands version 1.1.6

Answer (score 10):

`coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'` stable available

Answer (score 7):

My case. Error happened when update to `2.0.0`

Change to `1.1.5` works for me

```
coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5")
```

#### Updated 02/2023

Tried to change to `2.0.1` and above error is resolve but new error related to `OkHttpClient` happened.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class j$.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue
```

#### Updated 04/2023

`2.0.3` works fine now.

Comment: You can now upgrade to 2.0.1 and above. The error is fixed

Comment: @arshcaptano  Thanks. Build succeed now but app crashed after launched.

Comment: v2.0.2 has been released. The issue is not mentioned as a fix in the change log, but it seems to be the most stable. Thanks

Comment: 115 save my ass, 201~202 will give me Unsupported desugared library configuration version, please upgrade the D8/R8 compiler.

Comment: Yes, 2.0.2, 2.0.0 and 1.2.2 didn't solve the problem, but 1.1.5 did.

Comment: For now(11/5/2023) 2.0.3 got a new issue ERROR:: D8: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
org.gradle.workers.WorkerExecutionException: There were multiple failures while executing work items

Answer (score 6):

*[tl:dr]* Version `1.0.6` does not work with AGP `4.0.0`. Use `1.0.7` or `1.0.5` instead - they are the same.

Version `1.0.6` was released to address [issue 158502561](https://issuetracker.google.com/158502561), as there was an error in a dependent POM file, only affecting certain tools. However, I made a mistake, and `1.0.6` ended up being incompatible with Android Studio `4.0.0`, which is why `1.0.7` was released. `1.0.5` and `1.0.7` are identical, and `1.0.8` will be released later to address the POM issue in the dependent artifact.

Comment: is there anywhere we can find release notes for new versions of com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs?

Comment: At the moment there is no release notes/change log for `com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs`. The challenge here is that the code in https://github.com/google/desugar_jdk_libs is only part of the story. The full library desugaring includes the configuration (https://source.corp.google.com/r8/src/library_desugar/desugar_jdk_libs.json), which is shipped as a separate artifact (`com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs_configuration`) and a combination of AGP/D8/R8 that understands the configuration.

Answer (score 6):

Use this dependency for API 33 support. It is stable

```
dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
}
```

Although there is a newer version 2.0.0, but I having build issues with it.

Visit this link if you are interested in version 2.0.0
[google/desugar_jdk_libs](https://github.com/google/desugar_jdk_libs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same error after updating to Android 11 and the following worked for me

```
dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this library has some issues with other libs versions.

At this time the latest version is [2.0.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools/desugar_jdk_libs) but I got the same error with these (Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1, compileSdk 33).

So I found out I can use this version instead:

coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.8'

I hope it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the desugar_jdk version
for me 1.1.5 works although there is the latest version 2.0.4
but it depends.
see the versions of desugar_jdk.
[enter link description here](https://google/desugar_jdk_libs)
***i suggest to try any version and check which one works with your android version.***

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same issue it occurred because I enabled Desugaring in build.gradle (app level)

```
compileOptions {
        // for flutter_local_notification
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }

dependencies {
    
    // for flutter_local_notification
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
}
```

the version 1.2.2 was not compatible with my gradle I guess, so I changed it to

```
dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4'
}
```

then it worked

Answer (score 0):

For me, the **desugaring library was added**, but the project had **other compile-time errors**; however, it showed this message instead.

I tried to open the files I thought might cause compile-time errors based on my changes. After fixing the compile errors, it started building again.

Answer (score 0):

I used the current latest version

```
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.3'
```

and it was enabled in one of the modules but it didn't work also until I added it also to app gradle.

```
  compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
}
```

and it works fine for me